# Node-config: How to get not frozen data from config?

Tags: node.js, node-config

I've used [node-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) module in my project, and it pretty useful. But I've encountered use case which I don't know how to handle. Here is an example:
I have a huge config with a lot of nested objects, here is simplified one:

```
{
db:{
name:"name",
port:3000
}
}
```

When I make the first call of `config.get()` config object is being frozen, and all nested properties of config object are immutable. Which is good.

But `config.get()` returns also frozen object. So you can not do:

```
db=config.get("db");
db.port=2000;
```

Is there a way to get nested object form config which would be unfrozen? So I could change it.